# Nodemailer + Open relay server

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

Is there any documentation on : "How to send an email via open relay SMTP server" (i.e without passing any authentication data) while sending emails.

I tried "SMTP" option with passing just hostname and port# and removing "auth" data and did not work. I am wondering if any of you had similar requirement through node js. And possible ways leading to resolution ?

Answer (score 2):

That's the simplest one:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'your-open-relay-host',
    port: 25
}));
```

Ref: https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport